# Ignore service files when run perforce reconcile command

Tags: perforce

I would like to use "reconcile" command for adding new files to the changelist.
The issue is that all service files (files with suffix ,v) also are added to changelist.

Does anyone know how to prevent adding them to the changlist? 
Is it save to remove them?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a bit troubling that you've got ,v files showing up in your changelist.  Are your client workspace and your depot archive in the same place?  That's going to get very bad very quickly; the client and server should be in separate places.  Even if they're on the same machine, you want them in completely separate folders, much like you wouldn't have a web server root share a folder with your browser cache.

Comment: My workspace and depot are placed on one computer but in the different folders. I write small tool that interact with perforce via api, so it are test depot/workspace. I just thought that it is ok to have these files in workspace (like .orig file in git case). They are not normally in changelist, but reconcile adds them.

Comment: In general, the only files in your workspace should be the ones that your client is interacting with.  If you have a tool that interacts with Perforce via the client API, all it needs to have available to it are the client-side files, i.e. the workspace and the files that are synced to the workspace via client commands.  You can mix other files in there, but if you don't exclude them via your client view or P4IGNORE they'll get added by reconcile (as you've found) and/or removed by 'p4 clean' (which will essentially break your server if these are the live archive files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove them from your set of opened files, use 'p4 revert'.

You can also just delete those files from your changelist while editing the changelist prior to submit, but the files will remain open for add and you'll still need to revert them.

To prevent them from being added to the changelist in the first place, have a look at the P4IGNORE feature:

```
http://www.perforce.com/blog/120214/new-20121-p4ignore
```

Comment: Looks that using 'p4 revert' with ...,v pattern is fine solution in my case. Thanks.